# Saving A Table Permanently in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to make a contacts table in SQLite. When i commit the changes after inserting 2-3 rows of data, and try to access it after closing the current session, my records are no longer there..

This is what i have done:-

1.Made a directory `C:\Sites\databases>` to store all my database related data.
2. Created a database called contactlist_development, so when i type the command `dir` from 
`C:\Sites\databases>`, i can see my database.

This is where the problem starts:-

3.When i do (`C:\Sites\databases>sqlite3`). I am taken to the sqlite prompt, and when i make a table, its records don't get saved once i log out:-

```
sqlite>BEGIN TRANSACTION;
sqlite>CREATE TABLE contacts(Cid integer primary key autoincrement,first_name varchar(15),last_name varchar(15),address varchar(15),city varchar(15),state varchar(15),country varchar(15),phone double, email varchar(20));
sqlite>COMMIT;
```

Then,

```
sqlite>BEGIN TRANSACTION;
sqlite>INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(1,'Chetan','Dahal','Bal','Kathmandu','Nepal','50060','cheta@gmail.com'));
sqlite>COMMIT;
sqlite> Ctrl-C
```

Then when i login again, i don't get my records:(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are opening an in-memory database when you run:

```
C:\Sites\databases>sqlite3
```

Can you try running this instead?

```
C:\Sites\databases>sqlite3 contactlist_development
```

where `contactlist_development` is your database file.

Comment: @Chetan: Glad to help; feel free to accept as answer if you please.